# How to reshape the tensor in keras?

Tags: keras, reshape, tensor

I want to reshape a tensor, it's shape is (?,12,12,5,512) into (?,12,12,2560) shape of tensor.
Is there anyone who can help me?
My code is as below.

```python
conv5_1 = Conv3D(512, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop4_1) # conv5_1: Tensor("conv3d_10/Relu:0", shape=(", 12, 12, 5, 512), dtype=float32)
conv5_1 = Conv3D(512, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5_1)
drop5_1 = Dropout(0.2)(conv5_1) # drop5_1: Tensor("dropout_8/cond/Merge:0", shape=(", 12, 12, 5, 512), dtype=float32)
```

I want to make (?, 12, 12, 2560) shape of tensor after drop5_1.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`keras.layers.core.Reshape()` function is helpful (see also the [document](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape)).

```
reshaped = Reshape((12, 12, 2560))(drop5_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```py
reshaped = tf.reshape(drop5_1 , [-1,12,12,2560])
```